# Raise an exception if a variable is accessed before being "initialized" by another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module `settings.py`, which stores some variables to be used by other modules (for the sake of the example, let's call them `brightness` and `saturation`, though the actual module has a lot more and their initialization is much more complex).

This module is imported by other modules so that they can use `settings.brightness` and `settings.saturation` in their own code. However, these two variables aren't initialized - and are instead set to `None` when `settings` is imported. They have to be initialized by calling `settings.init()` at least once. (Why not initalize them automatically by putting `init()` at the end of `settings.py`? There are reasons... essentially, I have to do some other things first.)

Anyway, I'd like to be able to raise an exception if `brightness` or `contrast` were accessed before `init()` has been called. I was thinking about using some kind of object instead of `None` when `settings` is imported (which would raise an exception upon being accessed), but I can't think of a way to implement that, nor do I think that would be good design. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was thinking about using some kind of object instead of None when settings is imported (**which would raise an exception upon being accessed**)

This is not how it works... "accessing" an object is done by looking up this object's name on it's container object (via `object.__getattribute__()`, which is the implementation of the 'dot' operator), so only the container can detect "access". In your case, the container is a module, so you cannot override `__getattribute__`.

The possible solutions here are either to force client code to use a function to get the value (which is quite impractical) or - as explained by pasupati - to wrap the whole thing into a custom class and use properties to control access. You might eventually make this class a singleton...

NB:

> Because the Settings class would have to be assigned to some variable before being used. If the module name is settings and, say, it assigns settings = Settings() at the end, then, in order to reference this object, other modules would have to call settings.settings.get_brightness(). `from settings import settings` is another option, but that would be counterintuitive

No one forces you to name the module `settings.py` ;-)

Django is doing something similar (wrapping the settings in a custom class instance) and the module to import from is named 'django.conf' so you do `from django.conf import settings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter and setter using property instead

```
class setting:
     def __init__(self):
         self.__brightness=None

     @property
     def Brightness(self):
         if(self.__brightness==None):
            raise BaseException("Trying to access a value which is not set")
         else:
            return self.__brightness

     @Brightness.setter
     def Brightness(self,value):
         self.__brightness=value

s = setting()

try:
   s.Brightness
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)

s.Brightness=1
print(s.Brightness)
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same a mine but 20 minutes later.

Comment: @Loocid it's not _exactly_ the same - this one uses properties, which are much more pythonic for this use case than explicit getters.

Comment: You should be using a single leading underscore for the implementation attribute (no need for name mangling here), and name you properties in all_lower. Also, your class should be named "Settings" (capitalized),  the exception class should be a specific exception subclass and __definitly not__ a BaseException (hint : you shouldn't use BaseException at all unless you really know what it's for), and testing against `None` is canonically done with the identity operator `is` (`None` is garanteed to be a singleton).